# Can I integrate one or more SDK inside my own iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, sdk

I have built an SDK in which I need to take control and make a decision using Firebase remote configurations also I need to push some data from SDK to Firestore directly.

Can anyone please help me with the procedure for integration.
Or correct me if I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CocoaPods as the package manager for your SDK, you can define dependencies in the `Podspec` file. Firebase is available as [a CocoaPods pod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Firebase) so you can directly integrate it as a dependency. More information on how to define dependencies can be found in the [Podspec Syntax Reference](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency).